# Magento 2.3.3 Address update at checkout shows some Weird thing

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.3.3

I have attached the screenshots here, 
On checkout page customer is login, when I select first address and click on update, shows like this, anyone has idea about it? This is default braintree payment gateway configured.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're getting that error only for selected address ?

Comment: Only for first address, second address works fine.
Also checked with another customer account, same issue.

Comment: There is some issue with **BELLEVIEW** this name. So you're getting above error from this file.. **vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/legacy-build.min.js**

Answer (score 2):

I faced with this problem on v2.4.1 :)

The solution is to remove *_.values* for *currentBillingAddress().street* in  in the file "*vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/details.html*"

Should be: "**currentBillingAddress().street.join(', ')**"

Need to overwrite this html file in theme to apply.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for me.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25684