# Magento 2: Billing Address showing error in default checkout

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

In checkout page,while updating the billing address gives the strange error

[image]

Steps to reproduce this error:
Select the address from the address drop down and click on update button,it hides the address with same error but when we click on the other payment method it shows this error again

How to fix this ?
Magento version using 2.3.4 and PHP Version 7.3.18

Comment: This shouldn't happen. I tested it on a clean 2.3.4 installation and I couldn't reproduce it. It seems as if your address template has been overwritten. Kindly check `pub/static/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/[lang]/Magento_Checkout/template/billing-address.html` and compare it against this https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address.html

Comment: also billing form hided after that error

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this issue on 2.3.6 and I was able to solve it using this:

[Magento 2.3.3 Address update at checkout shows some Weird thing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293174/magento-2-3-3-address-update-at-checkout-shows-some-weird-thing)

I had to override one of the templates and change one line of code and it was fixed.